# How do I force the fresh render of a modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a modal that is generated on the first page load, but because this modal is rendered for each `node` on the page, it always has the wrong `node` value because the modal is always stale. i.e. if the rendered HTML has `node.id=7` on completed page load, it will always work on `node.id=7` even if you want it to render for `node.id=6`.

This is my modal:

```html
<div class="modal tagging fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tag User</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%=s imple_form_for node, url: add_tagged_user_node_path(node), method: :post do |f| %>
          <%=f .error_notification %>

            <div class="form-inputs">
              <%=f .association :user, label: "Users", collection: @users, as: :check_boxes, checked: node.user_tags %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
              <%=f .button :submit %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the trigger for that modal:

```
  <a class="plus" href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">&nbsp;</a>
```

What I would like to do is whenever the trigger is pressed, it basically performs a fresh page request for that modal - which would then populate the modal with the correct `node.id`.

How do I force that refresh when the button is pressed?

**Edit 1**

Here is the entire `index.html.erb` that the partials are called from:

```
      <% @nodes.each do |node| %>
            <!-- Upload Video Comment Popup -->
            <%= render partial: "shared/upload", locals: {node: node} %>

      <div class="box">
          <%= render partial: "nodes/box", locals: {node: node} %>
          <%= render partial: "nodes/comments", locals: {node: node} %>                         
      </div>
      <% end %> <!-- node -->
```

Here is the `nodes/box` partial, which contains the call we are interested in:

```
<!-- Author -->
              <div class="author clearfix">
                  <a class="avatar" href="#">
                    <%= image_tag node.user.avatar.url, size: "48x48", :class => "header img-circle" %>
                  </a>
                  <h5 class="name"><%= node.user.name %></h5>
                  <p class="date"><%= node.created_at.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") %>
                                        <span class="video-title-controls"><a href="#"><i class='fa fa-trash-o fa-lg pull-right'></i></a></span>
                                    </p>
              </div>
              <!-- Video -->
              <div class="video clearfix">
                  <% if node.is_video? %>
                      <%= raw yt_client.my_video(node.media.yt_video_id).embed_html5({:width => '280', :height => '300'}) %>
                  <% end %>
              </div>
              <!-- Titles -->
              <div class="titles clearfix">
                                <% if can? :manage, node %>
                  <h5><%= best_in_place node, :name, as: :input, activator: "#edit-node-title-#{node.id}" %> <%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>".html_safe, "#", id: "edit-node-title-#{node.id}" %></h5> 
                  <p><%= best_in_place node.media, :description, as: :input, activator: "#edit-node-desc-#{node.id}" %> <%= link_to "<i class='fa fa-pencil'></i>".html_safe, "#", id: "edit-node-desc-#{node.id}" %></p>
                                    <p><%= link_to "See video here", node_path(node) %></p>
                                    <% else %>
                  <h5><%= node.name %></h5> 
                  <p><%= node.media.description %></p>
                                    <% end %>                                       
              </div>
              <!-- Tags -->
              <div class="tags bootstrap-styles clearfix">

                                <% if controller_name == "nodes" %>
                                <p>
                                      <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#TagUsersModal">Tag Users</button>
                                </p>
                                <% end %>

                                    <% if node.tagged_users.empty? %>
                  <p class="tagged">In this video:</p>
                  <ul>
                    <li><%= link_to image_tag(node.user.avatar.url, size: "48x48", :class => "img-circle") , node.user %></li>
                  </ul>
                                    <% else %>
                  <p class="tagged">In this video:</p>              
                  <ul>
                    <% node.tagged_users.each do |tagged_user| %>
                                            <!-- <li><%#= link_to image_tag(tagged_user.avatar.url, size: "48x48", :class => "img-circle"), tagged_user %></li> -->
                                            <li><p><%= link_to tagged_user.email, tagged_user %></p></li>                                           
                                        <% end -%>
                  </ul>
                                    <% end %>
              </div>
```

The line that triggers this modal is:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#TagUsersModal">Tag Users</button>
```

It then triggers the modal at the top of the question.

Comment: You could achieve this via ajax, but I would urge you to use something like angular js to make the request and then bind the returned data to a view model that is referenced in your modal. This way you deal with data in your AJAX request rather than sending a rendered HTML string across.

Comment: @SimonH that's WAAAAAAAY overkill for what I want to do - just to render a modal that is unique for each object on the page. Do you have an example in jQuery of how I would do this?

Comment: There could be three ways, either you generate a different modal for each node id or you can populate your modal with form values as soon as you click on trigger link, which you can supply from anchor tag. or you can use ajax calls. Can you post your whole view.html.erb file and rails model? That would be helpful.

Comment: @marcamillion If you render modal for each node then isn't the problem that you call the modal by ID? What i mean is that you have multiple modals with same ID #TagUsersModal so it will always open the last one. Each modal should have unique ID. So change id of modal to correspond to node.id maybe simply "modalNode1" "modalNode2" etc. and trigger it  with <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNode1">Tag Users</button>.

Answer (score 2):

You need to destroy every modal window after close. In one of my projects I render custom modals for CRUD actions with bootsrap.

The code looks like this:

```
$(document).on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal'); 
});
```

Comment: Okay. Could you try to render content of 'modal-body' from controller? Here is sample code:

`class TasksController < ApplicationController

  layout false, only: [:new, :edit]

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end
  
end`

New and edit views are under tasks directory and they are just simply html files, just like your simple form above. Try to render this views via controller, not via index page.

Comment: ps. remember to add link on index page. for example:

 `<button class="btn-u" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-remote="<%= edit_task_path(task) %>">
    <i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> Edit task
   </button>`

Answer (score 0):

Add this javascript to your page:

```
(function() {
   //Destroy previously initialized boostrap modal ( it cache html )
   $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
   $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Forcing a fresh render of your modal with your Ruby variables isn't the most practical approach to this as it would require more revision than I could help with in one question. For a quick fix, I suggest rendering a modal for each node and hide/show the appropriate modal(s) with your trigger function.

Change the first line of your modal to include a data attribute with the `node.id`

```
<div class="modal tagging fade" data-id="<%= node.id %>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Render your modal for each node with something to this effect. ( Your code might use different partials names but I hope you get the gist.)

```
<% @nodes.each do |node| %>
  <%= render partial: 'nodes/modal', locals: { node: node }
<% end %>
```

Add the `node.id` to your button trigger

```
<button type="button" data-id="<%= node.id %>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#TagUsersModal">Tag Users</button>
```

Program your trigger function to show the modal with the `node.id` you want and hide the rest. Iterate over the modals and use the `data-id` from the `<button>` compared with the `data-id` of each modal to determine which modals should be hidden and which should be shown.

*If you'd like help on how your trigger function would be implemented, please update the question with the current code for the trigger function.*